# Remove only on Local any Remote branch no longer include in fetch

Tags: git, git-config, git-fetch, git-plumbing

for example, I have the following Branches:

- main -> tracking origin/main
- feature/f1 -> tracking origin/feature/f1
- feature/f2 -> tracking origin/feature/f2
  and in .gitconfig

```
[ remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

now I only want to see the feature-branches, therefor update .gitconfig to:

```
[ remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/feature*:refs/remotes/origin/feature/*
```

Is there any way to remove the local stored main branch, without deleting it on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any local branch at any time. This does not do anything to the remote branches.

```
git branch -d main
```

Just **DO NOT** `push` a delete command to your remote.

```
git push origin --delete main
```